# Customize comment notification e-mails with HTML

Tags: comments

I want to customize the  default content of notification e-mails i found the following codes. but i need to use HTML in my own content. 
would you please make it with HTML?
i do not know enough about PHP. so please do not refer me to some pages.
save me please. i need it really with HTML :

```
function wpd_comment_notification_text( $notify_message, $comment_id ){
// get the current comment and post data
$comment = get_comment( $comment_id );
$post = get_post( $comment->comment_post_ID );
// don't modify trackbacks or pingbacks
if( '' == $comment->comment_type ){
    // build the new message text
    $notify_message  = sprintf( __( 'A new reviewer wants to receive "%s"' ), $post->post_title ) . "\r\n";
    $notify_message .= sprintf( __('Author : %1$s'), $comment->comment_author ) . "\r\n";
    $notify_message .= sprintf( __('E-mail : %s'), $comment->comment_author_email ) . "\r\n";
    $notify_message .= sprintf( __('When you are logged, you can see details about the reviewer reputation here: %s'), get_comment_link( $comment_id ) ) . "\r\n";

    if ( user_can( $post->post_author, 'edit_comment', $comment_id ) ) {
        if ( EMPTY_TRASH_DAYS )
            $notify_message .= sprintf( __(''), admin_url("comment.php?action=trash&c=$comment_id") ) . "\r\n";
        else
            $notify_message .= sprintf( __(''), admin_url("comment.php?action=delete&c=$comment_id") ) . "\r\n";
        $notify_message .= sprintf( __(''), admin_url("comment.php?action=spam&c=$comment_id") ) . "\r\n";
    }
}
// return the notification text
return $notify_message;
}
add_filter( 'comment_notification_text', 'wpd_comment_notification_text', 20, 2 );
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found out it my self. we should add the following code to the Functions.php ti be able to sent Email via HTML codes:

```
<?php
function wpse27856_set_content_type(){
    return "text/html";
}
add_filter( 'wp_mail_content_type','wpse27856_set_content_type' );
?>
```

and then for customize the email, we should do like bellow to use HTML code in it:

```
<?php
function wpd_comment_notification_text( $notify_message, $comment_id ){
// get the current comment and post data
$comment = get_comment( $comment_id );
$post = get_post( $comment->comment_post_ID );
// don't modify trackbacks or pingbacks
if( '' == $comment->comment_type ){
    // build the new message text
    $notify_message = '<h1 style="font-family: tahoma; direction: rtl; margin-bottom: 0px !important; background: red; font-size: 22px; color: white; border: 1px solid red; padding: 10px 4px; text-align: center;">New Comment To You</h1>';

    $notify_message .= '</h1>';
    $notify_message .= '<h2 style="font-family: tahoma; direction: rtl; font-weight: normal; margin-bottom: 0px !important; font-size: 14px; border: 1px solid #ccc; border-bottom: 1px solid white; padding: 10px 4px; text-align: center;"><strong>';
    $notify_message .= sprintf( __( 'New comment on your post "%s' ), $post->post_title );
    $notify_message .= '</strong></h2>';
}
// return the notification text
return $notify_message;
}
add_filter( 'comment_notification_text', 'wpd_comment_notification_text', 20, 2 );
?>
```

Thanks anyway :)